# Making a class return null when empty

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I am currently working on a project. In a method, listPokemon, I am supposed to return all of the Pokemon in the pokedex, or return null if it's empty. I can't figure out how to make it return null, I'm a bit stuck. In case 1, when it's called, if listPokemon is null it should print "Empty." Here's the code I'm working with so far. Can someone help me?

listPokemon:

```
public String[] listPokemon() {

        String[] Poke = new String[counter];
        for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
            Poke[i] = pk[i].getSpecies();
        }

    }
    return Poke;
}
```

and case 1:

```
case 1:
                System.out.println();

                String[] pokemonList = pk.listPokemon();
                if (pokemonList == null)
                    System.out.println("Empty");
                else
                    for (int i = 0; i < pokemonList.length; i++) {
                        System.out.println((i+1) + ". " + pokemonList[i]);
                    }


                break;
```

Comment: According to what I understood `pokemonList.length == 0` also do the trick

Comment: what is `counter`?

Comment: @Andrew it keeps track of all the Pokemon there are

Comment: `if (counter == 0) return null;` ??? Seems pretty trivial.

Comment: null is # on empty() ,your list can contains null values ,which means your list is null ,but when it is empty ,it means your list has not any element.In your case you can add local list in your method intialize by null and return this list.

Comment: @Dukeling you would think, lol, but that didn't work for some reason.

Comment: You may want to post an [mcve] showing that then.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Comment: Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) before attempting to ask more questions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Returning null can be done literally with the statement `return null`. I'm not sure what the value of `counter` is in your example but it seems to me you need to rewrite your for loop:

```
public String[] listPokemon() {
    if(pk.length > 0){
        String[] Poke = new String[pk.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < pk.length; i++) {
            Poke[i] = pk[i].getSpecies();
        }

        return Poke;
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I suggest you look into List or the Collection API in general as it has neat ways to deal with lists: it has mehods isEmpty() and you can add append to lists without knowing the list size beforehand as you need with Arrays.

The Streams API in java 8 is even more powerful but much more complex.

Comment: Thank you! This was very help. I think I'm supposed to check that the list is empty and then return null, because I'm still getting the error that this doesn't return null for an empty list.

Answer (score -2):

This is an array of strings. Right? So if the first item in the array is empty, then it should return empty. I don't think an array can be null once it's already initialized.

Comment: It is. Can it return false?

Comment: The array is not null, but the items in the array can be null (up to `counter` elements exist in the array).

Comment: Okay. So try this. Check if the first element, pokemonList[0] is null. Then print empty. I think that would work. If the first element isn't null then its already been changed by your function and you can print whatever it was.

Comment: Method can return null no matter if array is initialized.